# How do I Add a Search that Queries a Table in the Database?

Tags: magento2, database, advanced-search

I'm working in Magento 2, and want to add a search to my header that uses 4 dropdown select menus to query a table I added in the database.

The 4 dropdowns will search one table for an id, and then that id will be looked for in a pivot table, which will point to the products table, finally returning the products to the user.

I already have the tables, Models, and Controllers from the CRUD module I built in the backend, I'm just not sure what files I need to edit/create and what directories they're in to get the search up.

**UPDATE**

I found this file,
`/app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/framework/Magento_Theme/layout` where the sections of the header are created, so I added my code, **but the containers aren't appearing on my site**:

```
....

<!-- Header Content -->
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" htmlClass="page-header__content">
    <container name="header-wrapper.grid-container" htmlClass="container" htmlTag="div" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
<!-- Header Content END -->

<!-- Added Code -->
<!-- Header Fitment Search -->
<referenceContainer name="header-fitment-search" htmlClass="page-header__fitment">
    <container name="header-fitment-search.grid-container" htmlClass="container" htmlTag="div" before="-" />
</referenceContainer>
<!-- Header Fitment Search END -->
<!-- Added Code END -->

...
```

Also not exactly sure how a .phtml file is called to be added into the container